# Append two arrays where only one dimension matches

Tags: python, numpy

i have two numpy arrays that look like this

```
a1 = array([p1,p2,p3])
a2 = array([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
```

I am looking to append them such that they would look like this:

```
array([p1,1,2,3],[p2,4,5,6],[p3,7,8,9])
```

i have tried various np.append, .concatenate, .insert, to no avail. most of the time i get an error that says "all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions". Anyone know the trick?

Comment: What are p1 ,p2, p3. Are they arrays or scalars ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.insert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
>>> a1 = np.array([10, 20, 30])
>>> a2 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> np.insert(a2, 0, a1, axis=1)
array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [20,  4,  5,  6],
       [30,  7,  8,  9]])
```